# Nested If Else Statement in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, if-statement, crystal-reports

I want to nest if-else statements in Crystal Reports, but I don't know the necessary syntax. How can I arrange something like this:

```
Local StringVar x;
If (IsNull({datatable.id}) or {datatable.id} ="") then
    x := ""
Else
   (If ToText({datatable.id})  <= {?parameter} Then
       x := "new"
Else
       x:= "")
```

Comment: Can you try using if..else... than If and Else?

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesnt work. I have tried with this code Local StringVar x;
If (IsNull({datatable.id}) or {datatable.id} ="") then 
    x := ""
If ToText({datatable.id})  <= {?parameter} Then 
        x := "new"
    Else
        x:= ""

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not c sharp.

In c sharp your code would look like this:

```
string x;
if (datatable?.id == null || datatable.id ="") {
    x = "";
}
else if (datatable.id <= Int32.Parse(parameter)) {
       x = "new";
}
else {
       x = "";
}
```

Bear in mind that I'm making heavy assumptions on what you are trying to achieve here. The purpose of the answer is to show you the c# syntax equivalent.

Comment: I'm using c# windows application forms for passing textbox value to crystal report and making a parameter with the following some of condition in crystal report. I have tried in many ways but, I could not solve it.

Comment: Doesn't the above code work for you? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have tried to implemented your code to my crystal report but, it still doesn't work and I didn't get any error message. What I've got is just x = "new" only and x wouldn't get null. It seems like that x = "" wouldn't appear in my crystal report.

Comment: Sorry what do you mena x wouldn't get null?

Comment: I meant, else x = " "; would not appear in my crystal report. I guess there is something wrong with my logic

Comment: Did new appear though? If id did it seems that the code does work, there is just something wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: Yes "New" has been appear but not for "Null". I do agree with you, maybe there is something wrong with my algorithm

Comment: ID has a value = 0001 and I want to make a condition If ID <= @parameter then x = "new" else x = "";

Comment: What is the value of the parameters? Is the id a string? If it is then you need to also parse it and make it integer.

Comment: I'm almost done with the true value, but still get error message. I go with this code;
Local StringVar x;                                                                                                   If ToNumber({MOLabelEpson.ODD_FLEX_S4_A}) <= ToNumber({?lastmo}) Then x := "Reprint"
Else x := " "                                                                                                         The parameters value is String.